How can I prevent Dark Reader Chrome extension from using so much CPU when turned off (accounts for 60% of Chrome CPU time!)?
I turned off the Dark Reader Chrome extension:

Yet, it takes huge amount of CPU (accounts for 60% of Chrome CPU time!):

How can I prevent Dark Reader Chrome extension from using so much CPU when turned off?
I use Windows 10, Version 127.0.6533.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), .

Disable or uninstall it? Use a different chrome profile where it's not installed?

Makes one wonder why an extension is using any CPU -- is it mining cryptocurrency in the background??

@DrMoishePippik yeah that sounds like some heavy mining operation going on in the background, a pretty serious bug or some parameters I missed in the configuration.

@DavidPostill if wanted to check if I had missed some parameters in the extension configuration. But at that point looks like one has to get rid of it indeed

Report it to the author first of all. It has a lot of good ratings, so likely a bug.

Looks like it is a bug with the Dark Reader Chrome extension. As DavidPostill commented, just disable or uninstall the Dark Reader Chrome extension.
